# Joomla component for multiple language

Tags: joomla, components, multilingual

In one of my multi language website, there is a custom component. In which we can create "CategorY" and products under category.

It has been implemented in the backend and front end and its working fine in english.

But my client need same component in the "arabic" ( which is my second language). Is there any simple way to do this. Now in arabic session also "english" is showing.

Best of my knowledge, We can take 2 inputs from the backend. like title_english, title_arabic and show accordingly. So my table looks like

```
id    |    title_arabic      |      english_title
------+----------------------+----------------------
1     |   title in arabic    |    English title
------+----------------------+----------------------
2     |   title in arabic    |    English title
------+----------------------+----------------------
3     |   title in arabic    |    English title
------+----------------------+----------------------
4     |   title in arabic    |    English title
------+----------------------+----------------------
5     |   title in arabic    |    English title
------+----------------------+----------------------
6     |   title in arabic    |    English title
------+----------------------+----------------------
```

My question is is there any wat to differentiate the language in the front end and show the title accordingly ? something like

```
if($language=="english")
    echo $item->english_title;
else 
    echo $item->title_arabic;
```

Please help
Thanks for advance

Answer (score 2):

You can find it in the below URLs

http://multilingual-joomla-demo.cloudaccess.net/

http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_multi-language_support

http://cool-tricks.net/create-a-joomla-multilanguage-website/

http://www.scribd.com/doc/82768844/Joomla-2-5-multi-language-website-without-using-3rd-extensions-in-10-steps

Comment: or, you could use joomfish or falang and not code it yourself. You just need to create an xml file describing your table and they will be handled by either component.